# Laravel / Angular update RESTfull

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, laravel

So I would like to update a record in Laravel using Angular.
This is what I have, but i'm afraid it's not best practice?

So basically, what I'm doing now is:
1. I get the data form my single post with the 'show' function (I guess this is where I'm already wrong, should't that be handeled in my update function)?
2. I populate my form with this data
3. I try to update the data with the 'update' function.
I don't think this is RESTfull?

Angular.js:
Factory show and update:

```
update : function(
            id,
            rideEdit
        )
        {
            //rideData.ridedate = $filter('date')(rideData.ridedate, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            console.log(rideEdit);
            return $http({
                method: 'PATCH',
                url: '/api/rides/' + id,
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                data: $.param(rideEdit)
            });
        },
        show : function(
            id
        )
        {
            return $http.get('/api/rides/' + id);
        }
```

Angular.js: EditController (this is where I populate my form, and cath the button clicks, ...).

```
        $scope.rideEdit = {};
    var id = $stateParams.id;
    // Alles nemen van 1 record
    Ride.show(id)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.rideEdit.Dataname = data.name;
            $scope.rideEdit.Description = data.description;
            $scope.rideEdit.datetime = data.ridedatetime;
            $scope.rideEdit.persons = data.ridepersons;
            $scope.rideEdit.vertrekpunt = data.ridevertrekpunt;
            $scope.rideEdit.eindpunt = data.rideeindpunt;
        });

    $scope.updateRide = function() {
        console.log($scope.rideEdit);
        Ride.update(id, $scope.rideEdit)
            .success(function (data) {
                ToastFactory
                    .show('Rit aangepast!');
                $location.path('/home');
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                ToastFactory
                    .show(error);
            });
    };
```

Laravel:
Ridescontroller:

```
 public function index()
{
    $results = Ride::with('user')->get();
    return $results;
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  StoreRideRequest  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(StoreRideRequest $request)
{
    $ride = new Ride($request->all());
    Auth::user()->rides()->save($ride);
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //$results = Ride::find($id)->with('user')->get();
    $result = Ride::find($id);
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $updateride = Ride::findOrFail($id);
    $updateride->update($request->all());
}
```

Everything works (except for the update). So I have 2 questions:
1. Is this method OK with RESTfull?
2. If it is, what's wrong with my update function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer part 2 of my question:

My namingconvention wasn't correct. The names of the fields I sent with the update weren't the same as the name's in the database. Changing them accordingly solved the update problem.